# Хочу найти нужный байт в файле bmp,  но ничего не получается.

Tags: файлы

Имею файл 32-х разрядный bmp сделанный в Photoshop. Пытаюсь найти значение пиксела в самой середине картинки. Адрес расчитал следующим образом: к $36 (столько занимает заголовок файла bmp за которым следует массив пикселов) прибавляю 5000 * 4  (т.к. картинка размером 100х100, то пикселей 10000, это число делим на два, чтобы найти пиксел посередине и умножаем на четыре, т.к. пиксел занимает 4 байта (синий,зелёный,красный, альфа-канал). Получаю адрес $4E56, по которому предполагаю увидеть число $0000ffff, но вместо этого вижу совершенно непонятное число, непонятно откуда взявшееся:

[image]

---

Для справки: [формат BMP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP)

---

Кому не сложно, пжл найдите этот оффсет серединной точки картинки. [Вот ссылка на BMP](http://cs11141.userapi.com/u145392289/-14/x_1fc7c425.jpg)

Comment: Видимо неверно считаете смещение (``DWORD   bfOffBits;`` - это смещение учитываете?). Найдите первый пиксель, серидину потом можно искать уже...

Comment: Я учитывал все смещения эксперементальным путём: создавая картинки 1х1, меняя байты и наблюдая за результатами. Так что пикселы начинаются с оффсета $36 - это 100%

Comment: Даже если я ошибаюсь, то моя ошибка может быть максимум на $36 байтов, для меня это не страшно, т.к. пятно альфа-канала довольно крупное.

Comment: Пойдите от обратного. Разместите в центре картинки пиксель цвета , скажем, 0xDEADBEEF )
И ищите его в файле. Может быть это что-то прояснит.

Comment: ОФФТОП: @ололо, пожалуйста уважайте чужой труд и не удаляйте свои вопросы, раз уж кто-то потрудился дать вам ответ. Каждый раз писать администрации для восстановления удаленного вопроса - напряжно. 

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: @ололо, по ссылке не bmp а jpeg. Лучше воспользоваться файлообменником, например rghost.ru.

Comment: Вообще рецепт такой: в графическом редакторе меняем цвет центральной точки и сохраняем измененный рисунок под другим именем. Дальше побайтно сравниваем два файла (например в том же хекс-редакторе) и смотрим где они отличаются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле номер серединной точки массива пикселей 100х100 (почти серединной, т.к. в середине находятся 4 точки,  но в моём случае это не существенно) вычисляется след.образом: (100 * 100)/2+100/2. (Забыл добраться до середины строчки, т.е. прибавить 100/2) Сапасибо всем за помощь!